# How To Create Registry Keys Using Microsoft.Win32.Registry C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, outlook, registry

I am wanting to write directly to the registry using `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`. I can do this is a reg file like so:

```
swreg = File.AppendText(strRegPath); //Opens the file:

swreg.WriteLine(@"[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\OMI Account Manager\Accounts\user@domain.com");
swreg.WriteLine("\"DCEmail\"=dword:00000002");
swreg.WriteLine("\"POP3 Server\"=\"10.0.0.200\""); 
swreg.WriteLine("\"POP3 Port\"=dword:0000006e");
```

This creates a reg file, and I can execute the file which create the reg keys. I have tried to something similar using `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` like so:

```
var RKOutlook = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\OMI Account Manager\Accounts");

if (RKOutlook.OpenSubKey("user@domain.com") == null)
{
    RKOutlook.CreateSubKey("user@domain.com");
    RKOutlook = RKOutlook.OpenSubKey("user@domain.com", true);
}
```

However I receive an `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled` error. How can I achieve writing directly to the registry without using a reg file?

Comment: Where was the NullReferenceException?

Comment: user@domain.com doesn't mean anything.  Please post valid code.

Comment: @iabbott the error is at "if (RKOutlook.OpenSubKey(user@domain.com) == null)"

Comment: Check `RKOutlook` is not null before trying to open a subkey

Comment: @iabbott it is null before it hits the if statement

Comment: @nate which means this: `@"Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\OMI Account Manager\Accounts"` does not exist. You'll have to create that as well

Comment: @nate - please be respectful. user@domain.com is not valid, it must be enclosed in a string, i.e. "user@domain.com" since that's the argument .OpenSubKey expects.

Comment: @DarrenDavies is was in there, when I posted it, not sure what happened, fixed it thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d.aspx) will return `null` if the operation fails, you then assign this value to `RKOutlook` and attempt to access `.OpenSubKey` (Probably why you get the exception).

You should also check that the object is not `null` before attempting to access the `OpenSubKey` method:

```
  if (RKOutlook != null && RKOutlook.OpenSubKey(user@domain.com) == null)
  {
     RKOutlook.CreateSubKey(user@domain.com);
     RKOutlook = RKOutlook.OpenSubKey(user@domain.com, true);
  }
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - yes, but the OP is effectively doing `null.OpenSubKey` which throws the exception

Comment: Exactly, but it is not relates to `OpenSubKey` behavior.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - if RKOutlook is null and then you attempt to call the `OpenSubkey` method, it will result in a NRE, which is the problem.

Comment: RKOutlook has to == null, so I can create the key

Comment: @nate - `OpenSubKey("user@domain.com")` needs to `== null` - `RKOutlook` is the object, if it's `null` it throws the nullreferenceexception. Remember you are invoking the `OpenSubKey` method via the object (That needs an instance)

Comment: @DarrenDavies That makes since, I see I am going at this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

[Reading from and writing to Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf3xkta.aspx)

This code is in VB.NET but that can be translated to C#
The following code shows how to read a string from HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regVersion = null;
dynamic keyValue = "Software\\Microsoft\\TestApp\\1.0";
regVersion = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyValue, false);
int intVersion = 0;
if (regVersion != null) {
    intVersion = regVersion.GetValue("Version", 0);
    regVersion.Close();
}
```

The following code reads, increments, and then writes a string to HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

```
var regVersion = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\TestApp\\1.0", true);
if (regVersion == null) {
    // Key doesn't exist; create it.
    regVersion = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\TestApp\\1.0");
}

int intVersion = 0;
if (regVersion != null) {
    intVersion = regVersion.GetValue("Version", 0);
    intVersion = intVersion + 1;
    regVersion.SetValue("Version", intVersion);
    regVersion.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to use this as written. I am getting this error and I am using Microsoft.Win32 "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?"

Comment: Well add that dll in, in Visual studios solution explorer you'll see references, right click -> add reference in .NET tab select Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core